# Error 000666, does not have OID with Locate Features Along Route in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, objectid, error-000666

I'm trying to take a bunch of point data and determine what points of surveyed lines are closest to each point.  To this end I have put together a model that loops through the line features and in each loop it selects the survey points that intersect the line, creates Thiessen polygons from those points, then uses Locate Features Along Routes to generate a table showing what is covered where.  The problem is that the Locate Features along Route tool consistently (but not universally, for some reason) spits out an error (#000666) saying that the input features do not have OIDs.

I've tried the Make Query Table method, but that doesn't work either, since the Thiessen polygons are wiped each time through the loop the Query Table loses the definitions of what fields to take, resulting in a different error, since the Make Query Table method will spit out a table, rather than a shapefile, if you don't check the option to include the shape in the input.

Does anyone know of another workaround to give those polygons OIDs?  Or of another way to get a similar result without using the clearly buggy Locate Features Along Routes?

[image: The part that's causing the headaches]

Comment: Could it be a scenario that your line does not select any points so no Thiessen polygons are generated, thus the locate tool throws an error?

Comment: That certainly seemed to be the problem.  I added in a Get Count for the point file and that error stopped occurring.